# mssing posts on pages timesline

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graph, facebook-fql, tagging

I wanna get all input from my pages timeline. so I read graph.facebook.com/pageid/feed with the page token. but some posts are missing - even when I try using FQL

e.g. these are

- a user posts to his own wall and marked my page in his status or picture
- a user posts to his own wall and mentioned my page as the location for this post
- the recommendations

also in /tagged/ these posts won't appear. Is there any chance to get them?

thx
me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Facebook shows more within their webapp than they make available via the API. What gets returned depends on the poster's privacy settings.

In my experience, if the post isn't marked "public", then it won't be returned by the API, even if it is visible to you from within the Facebook.